# Create a listview layout with sections in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to implement a long listview like below. There are sections and each has a title and a variable amount of images. What is the best way to tackle this issue?

Should I create a section widget and use that in the listview builder?

[image]

Comment: you may try this package : https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_headers

Comment: Try doing a ListView of Columns which contain a Text widget as a title and a GridView to show the images.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve thst with sliver list and sliver grid  see [slivers](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverList-class.html)